# default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'x'

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone enlighten me what is going wrong with this code:

```
template<typename S, typename T = int>
void foo() {
    extern int x;
}
```

Error message with GCC 5.5 and --std=c++11:

```
test.cpp: In function 'void foo()':
test.cpp:4:16: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'x'
     extern int x;
                ^
```

However, Clang 3.8 compiles the same code successfully.

For this very simple sample, there's a workaround putting the `extern` declaration out of function. But for the actual code, the `extern` declaration must be in `foo` scope, so the workaround is not available.

I search with Google and find a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57775) reported 7 years ago and still opened. I'm not sure if I get the same bug

Comment: Can you do a small upgrade to your toolchain? GCC 6.1 Accepts it https://godbolt.org/z/N-SZ24

Comment: @StoryTeller , thank you so much! It works. And the website is very interesting :)